# Hide div on second click

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I have a piece of code that shows a div on click of the parent div. I want to be able to hide this child div when I click the parent div again.
I can't figure this out.

I don't understand if it has to be in a separate function or not? How do I check if it was clicked before (maybe if the child div is shown? really confused on how to do that).

Thanks for your help,

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('article-title')[i]
    .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       articleDescription.style.display = "block";
 }
```

My code is very very long, but the showing the div on click works perfectly. Hence me not posting the entire code. I just need some help in seeing what direction I need to head into to make it disappear after a second click

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a condition to check does that child element have the style`display:block` or not. It's a toggle function.

```js
var articleTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('article-title');
 for(let i=0; i<articleTitle.length; i++){
  articleTitle[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    let target = event.target;
    let articleDescription = target.firstElementChild;
       articleDescription.style.display =  (articleDescription.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
 });
 };
```

```html
<div class="article-title">parent
  <div class="article-description">child</div>
</div>
<div class="article-title">parent
  <div class="article-description">child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your Problem gets easier if you add classes on your elements and handle the hiding via CSS.

jQuery Example:

```js
$(".parent").click(function(){
  $(".parent").toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```css
.child{
  display: none;
}

.parent.clicked .child{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
parent
<div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, just try to use pure javascript. Since the question didn't have any jQuery in it, your answer shouldn't either (unless the person who asked the question says it's fine)

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below should work for you. Basically, it uses `window.getComputedStyle(this.children[0]).getPropertyValue("display")` to check if the element is visible or not. If it is visible, it shows the div. If it is not visible, it hides the div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```js
articleDescription = document.getElementsByClassName("article-description");
articleTitles = document.getElementsByClassName('article-title');

for (var i = 0; i < articleTitles.length; i++) {
  articleTitles[i]
    .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    
      if (window.getComputedStyle(this.children[0]).getPropertyValue("display") == "none") {
        this.children[0].style.display = "block";
      }
      else if (window.getComputedStyle(this.children[0]).getPropertyValue("display") == "block") {
        this.children[0].style.display = "none";
      }
    })
}
```

```css
.article-title {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.article-description {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-title">
  <div class="article-description"></div>
</div>
<div class="article-title">
  <div class="article-description"></div>
</div>
<div class="article-title">
  <div class="article-description"></div>
</div>
<div class="article-title">
  <div class="article-description"></div>
</div>
<div class="article-title">
  <div class="article-description"></div>
</div>
```